# Jquery Nestable output into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable
I am using above source by David Bushell to create a nested lists that are drag-drop editable.

The database 'sortable' that I am trying to edit has 4 columns: id, name, parent_id, display_order

```
(`id`, `name`, `parent_id`, `display_order`)
(1, 'item 1', '2', 1),
(2, 'item 2', '0', 3),
(3, 'item 3', '', 1),
(4, 'item 4', '0', 2),
(5, 'item 5', '0', 1),
(6, 'item 6', '', 1),
(7, 'item 7', '', 1),
(8, 'item 8', '1', 1),
(9, 'item 9', '1', 2);
```

two ordered lists are generated, one with all integer values for parent_id, where 0 is the top level and one where the top level has parent_id=' '. The output of the above database is shown on the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c9m5r5p2/6/

I am unable to add the jquery.nestable.js from the github source, making the dragging/dropping not possible. The function generating the output has been added though

```
 var updateOutput = function(e)
{
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');
    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));
    } else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};

// output initial serialised data
updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
updateOutput($('#nestable2').data('output', $('#nestable2-output')));
```

However, imagine I would drag 'item 8' to the top level and make 'item 7' a child of 'item 4', 'Output 1' and 'Output 2' would be:

```
output 1: [{"id":2,"children":[{"id":1},{"id":9}]},{"id":8},{"id":4,"children":[{"id":7}]},{"id":5}]

output 2: [{"id":3},{"id":6}]
```

Due to lack of knowledge about JQuery, I do not know how to pass these new values to a (php?) function and edit the DB. Is this also possible without having a 'save' button? Most likely I am looking for an easy call.

Comment: A question - if you are always going to be having some nested structure with utilizes a JSON serialization back and forth between your database, why would you even bother to try to save a flattened hierarchy representation of the values in MySQL vs. just storing the resulting JSON for the whole display element.  You can simply retrieve the JSON from DB and use it to recreate the nested control on intial page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As danielson317's answer didn't give a full solution, I decided to post the final outcome after some more searching and asking([Alter and post Jquery array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275586/alter-and-post-jquery-array/32275790#32275790))

In order to make the post the drag/drop to a .php file a few edits had to be made on the page where the dragging/dropping happens. A variable 'last_touched' was added to be able to know if 'nestable' or 'nestable2' is posted:

```
var last_touched = '';
var updateOutput = function(e)
{   
var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
    output = list.data('output');
if (window.JSON) {
    output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));

        $.post('process_update.php', 
            { 'whichnest' : last_touched, 'output' : output.val() }, 
            function(data) {
                console.log('succes')
            }
        );
} else {
         output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};

// activate Nestable for list 1
$('#nestable').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', function(){ last_touched = 'nestable'; })
.on('change', updateOutput );

// activate Nestable for list 2
$('#nestable2').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', function(){ last_touched = 'nestable2'; })
.on('change', updateOutput );

// output initial serialised data
updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
updateOutput($('#nestable2').data('output', $('#nestable2-output')));
```

The array is sent to process_update.php, here we decode the string array using`json_decode($_POST['output'],true);` . This array we compare to the data in the database, we compute the differences and lastly update the values.

```
<?php
include('config/setup.php');

//Nestable
if ($_POST['whichnest'] == 'nestable'){

    //Creating from_db unnested array
    $from_db = array();

    $sql = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT page_id, parent_id, display_order FROM pages WHERE parent_id != ''");
    $sql -> execute();
    $sql -> bind_result($page_id,$parent_id,$display_order);

    while($sql -> fetch()) {
        $from_db[$page_id] = ['parent'=>$parent_id,'order'=>$display_order];
    }

    //Function to create id =>[ order , parent] unnested array
    function run_array_parent($array,$parent){  
        $post_db = array();     
        foreach($array as $head => $body){
            if(isset($body['children'])){
                $head++;
                $post_db[$body['id']] = ['parent'=>$parent,'order'=>$head];
                $post_db = $post_db + run_array_parent($body['children'],$body['id']);
            }else{
                $head++;
                $post_db[$body['id']] = ['parent'=>$parent,'order'=>$head]; 
            }
        }

        return $post_db;
    }

    //Creating the post_db unnested array
    $post_db = array();
    $array = json_decode($_POST['output'],true);
    $post_db = run_array_parent($array,'0');

    //Comparing the arrays and adding changed values to $to_db
    $to_db =array();

    foreach($post_db as $key => $value){
        if( !array_key_exists($key,$from_db) || ($from_db[$key]['parent'] != $value['parent']) || ($from_db[$key]['order'] != $value['order'])){
            $to_db[$key] = $value;
        }   
    }

    //Creating the DB query
    if (count($to_db) > 0){
        $query = "UPDATE pages";
        $query_parent = " SET parent_id = CASE page_id";
        $query_order = " display_order = CASE page_id";
        $query_ids = " WHERE page_id IN (".implode(", ",array_keys($to_db)).")";

        foreach ($to_db as $id => $value){
            $query_parent .= " WHEN ".$id." THEN ".$value['parent'];
            $query_order .= " WHEN ".$id." THEN ".$value['order'];
        }
        $query_parent .= " END,";
        $query_order .= " END"; 

        $query = $query.$query_parent.$query_order.$query_ids;

        //Executing query
        $sql = $dbc -> prepare($query);
        $sql -> execute();
        $sql -> close();
    }
}
//nestable 2
elseif($_POST['whichnest'] == 'nestable2'){
    // More of the same!
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to perform an ajax request. On update you call a function called `updateOutput`. I would add an ajax call to the bottom of it Something like:

```
updateOutput = function(e) {
    // All your processing here...

    // Ajax request.
    values = {output:output}
    $.post('/myurl', values, function(data) { 
      console.log(success)
    });
}
```

On the php side you would receive the data via post and process it

```
function processDragUpdate()
{
    if (!isset($_POST['output'])
    {
      die('Missing data');
    } 
    $data = json_decode($_POST['output'])

    // Loop through data and process it and save to db.

    // Depending on your system you may need to exit here.
    die('success');
}
```

Depending on how your server is setup calling this function could be as simple as creating a file called myurl.php. Inside would look something like:

```
<?php
// Any required libraries to do your processing such as your mysql functions and database information and whatever library has the above function stored in it.
include_once '/libraries/stuff.php'

processDragUpdate();
```

### Update

Tried to make the code more specific to the use case and added some basic how to php info. Still not sure I'm actually answering the question. I'm just talking about how to use basic ajax.

Comment: Probably what i am looking for, however i do not know how exactly to do it, which variables where. I have added the output function to my post. Could you possibly edit your answer with my output? Does this run the update function after every drag or not? Do I call the phpfunction from a different page?

Comment: If the code above doesn't push you in the right direction you may need to look into some fundamentals Start Here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: @Pepe Added some more info and tried to make it more specific to your use case. Does that make it a little more clear? Also make sure to check out the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @ danielson317 indeed, I am missing the fundamental knowledge about ajax. Might take me some time to exactly figure out everything, but i'm pretty sure that was what i was looking for. I will accept your answer once i find enough time to figure it out. Thanks

Comment: alright, i can't do it. I do know where to add the ajax request (if statement), but i do not know which variable to pass (or how to add a value so i know which top-level parent i'm working with in the php).

Comment: You'll need to ask a different question for that. We are already beyond the scope of a single stack overflow question. Sounds like you need a consult or a friend who knows php to help you out. I just don't have the time to do that kind of consulting.