# Alter and post Jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays, post

https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable I am using above source by David Bushell to create nested lists that are drag-drop editable. I have two (interconnected) main lists with their id's being #nestable and #nestable2

The two lists can be seen on this JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/zs8bm237/ . At the bottom the github code added two textarea with id's #nestable-ouput and #nestable2-output . These show the hierarchal structure of the two lists. This output changes after each drag-drop action to the new structure. For the state shown in the JSFiddle the shown output would be:

```
output #nestable-output: [{"id":2,"children":[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":8},{"id":9}]}]},{"id":4},{"id":5}]

output #nestable2-output: [{"id":3},{"id":6},{"id":7}]
```

The JQuery code used to create these lists is given below. I have been working further on the code(see comments in code).

I want to send:

- the created list to a php file called process_update.php
- on top of that I need to know if it is #nestable or #nestable2 that is being send through, either by sending an extra post variable, **or** by editing the lists just before they are send through to:

  ```
  output #nestable-output: [{"id":0,"children":[{"id":2,"children":[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":8},{"id":9}]}]},{"id":4},{"id":5}]}]

  output #nestable2-output: [{"id":'',"children":[{"id":3},{"id":6},{"id":7}]}]
  ```

The javascript:

```
var updateOutput = function(e)
{
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');
    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));

            //Need to send altered array through here!
            $.post('process_update.php', ???output???, function(data) {
            console.log('succes')
            });
    } else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};

// activate Nestable for list 1
$('#nestable').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', updateOutput);

// activate Nestable for list 2
$('#nestable2').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', updateOutput);

// output initial serialised data
updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
updateOutput($('#nestable2').data('output', $('#nestable2-output')));
```

I have been trying, but as I am awful with JQuery I do not know which variable to alter and how.

EDIT: The 'serialize' function called as defined in the github project:

```
        serialize: function()
    {
        var data,
            depth = 0,
            list  = this;
            step  = function(level, depth)
            {
                var array = [ ],
                    items = level.children(list.options.itemNodeName);
                items.each(function()
                {
                    var li   = $(this),
                        item = $.extend({}, li.data()),
                        sub  = li.children(list.options.listNodeName);
                    if (sub.length) {
                        item.children = step(sub, depth + 1);
                    }
                    array.push(item);
                });
                return array;
            };
        data = step(list.el.find(list.options.listNodeName).first(), depth);
        return data;
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can POST multiple variables in data like so:

```
        $.post('process_update.php', 
            { 'whichnest' : 'nestable2', 'output' : output }, 
            function(data) {
                console.log('succes')
            }
        );
```

Then on server side, reference `$_POST['whichnest']` and `$_POST['output']`

Update based on your comment question below. I've used a global `last_touched` which we modify with the appropriate value on `change()`

```
var last_touched = '';
var updateOutput = function(e)
{
    var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
        output = list.data('output');
    if (window.JSON) {
        output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));//, null, 2));

            //Need to send altered array through here!
            $.post('process_update.php', 
                { 'whichnest' : last_touched, 'output' : output.val() }, 
                function(data) {
                    console.log('succes')
                }
            );
    } else {
        output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
    }
};

// activate Nestable for list 1
$('#nestable').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', function(){ last_touched = 'nestable'; })
.on('change', updateOutput );

// activate Nestable for list 2
$('#nestable2').nestable({
    group: 1
})
.on('change', function(){ last_touched = 'nestable2'; })
.on('change', updateOutput );

// output initial serialised data
updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));
updateOutput($('#nestable2').data('output', $('#nestable2-output')));
```

Comment: as nestable and nestable2 call the same function, how do I know which one it is? it also gives this error: TypeError: 'checkValidity' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLTextAreaElement.

Comment: Console gives TypeError: 'checkValidity' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLTextAreaElement.
Note that i do not need the textarea's... I just need the stored element

Comment: I have changed 'output' : output to 'output' : output.val() and that seems to fix the error. Any way I can check what is being send through? However, dragging dropping doesn't seem to change the output anymore! (guess problem is at the .on('change',....)

Comment: @Pepe see the update, what if we assign `last_touched` variable on click, and revert on change back to what you had from nestable example?

Comment: no errors and the output changes as supposed. Any idea how i can check if the correct values are posted?

Comment: Yes - just before `$.post()` line, put: `console.log( output.val() );` and check browser console to see the data that would have been posted. You can also look in the "NET" tab of Firebug (if you use such tool) to examine the HTTP AJAX request

Comment: the data passed by output.val() works! However console.log( last_touched ); outputs a blank line, seems like it doesn't change!
EDIT: i changed .on('click' to .on('change' and that seems to work! Any more notes?